# Why are Talmudical hermeneutics necessary to understand Torah Law?

Tags: midrash, pentateuch-chumash

Most books are written in such a way that everything that the author wants to communicate is spelled out clearly. The Torah is not such a book. Talmudical hermeneutics (for instance, the 13 rules of Rabbi Ishmael) are necessary to understand what the Author wanted to communicate with respect to halacha. My question is why was the Torah written in such a fashion?

Comment: Very similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/17311

Comment: As an example consider that the written torah could not have had all the halachos of electricity. The words did not yet exist and would not have been understood. Consider the laws of driving a car on shabbos when cars had not yet been invented.

Comment: similar http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/26659/759

Comment: @msh210 IMHO if you read them carefully, they are not dupes. This question asks why the author chose to leave certain parts oral. The other question picks up where this question ends. Granted that for whatever reason parts will be left out, why not at least mentions the fact that there ommissions.

Comment: @mevaqesh I saw your comment but don't have time now to act on it (reread the posts etc) alas. If I don't respond within a day or so and it's not reopened and your comment isn't deleted, then please ping me again here or in [chat]

Comment: @mevaqesh I think the questions are the same literally and are even understood as such by e.g. Matt and Baby Seal (in their respective answers to the other question: they answer that question as if it were the same as this question). Therefore, I'm inclined to keep this closed. What do you think, Craig Feinstein?

Answer (score 2):

Like can been found in Sefer Orot HaGra, on the section dealing with Torah, the Vilna Gaon expresses the idea that all events and all people from the beginning of time to the end are contained within the five books of Moshe. He explains that all these hermeneutical details are necessary in order to include every detail of creation.